# Not showing user during iteration if user already belongs to "group" relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this relationship where User can create a document(trip) and invite other users to a group that belongs to that document. My relationship indicates that "Group" has a user_id and trip_id column, so for every user I invite, a new Group record will be created in the database.

When I am inviting other users, I only want users who are NOT in the group to appear. Users who are already in the group should not show up, but my view still shows the users.

I've been playing around with `<% if !friend.trips.include?(@trip)%>`, but I can't seem to get the correct view. The record is being created in the database correctly.

Also, when I am viewing groups/new.html.erb, this is the url `http://localhost:3000/groups/new?id=2`, where the id is the trip_id.

My question:

1. Am I using restful convention? That is, should I be using the new method here (as is) or should I be using the index method instead?
2. How do I iterate through each friend's groups to make sure that none of the group's trip_id is equivalent to @trip.id?

Thanks!

view (/groups/new.html.erb)

```
<% if !@friends.blank? %>
  <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
     <% if !friend.trips.include?(@trip)%>
          <%= link_to groups_path(:user_id => friend.id, :trip_id => @trip.id), 
                                  :method => :post, :action => 'create' do %>
            <div id="addfriend_totrip_button_groupsnew">add friend to trip</div>
          <% end %>
    <% end %>   
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

groups_controller.rb

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:update, :create, :destroy]

  def new
   @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
   @user = User.find(current_user)
   @group = Group.new
   @friends = @user.friends.all 
  end

  def create
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @group = Group.create(:user_id => @user.id, :trip_id => @trip.id)

    if @group.save
      flash[:success] = "Friend added to group."
      redirect_to groups_path(:id => @trip.id)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not add friend."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips, :through => :groups
  has_many :trips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups
end
```

trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :traveldeal
  has_many :groups

  has_many :users, :through => :groups
end
```

group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have `has_many :trips` called twice in your `User` model. I understand you have two different types of `User`-`Trip` relationships (one directly, and one through `Group`), but you can't give both the same name, otherwise one will hide the other. Try defining your `User` model like this:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_trips, :through => :groups,
                         :class_name   => "Trip"
  has_many :trips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups

  def all_trips
    Trip.joins(:groups).where({:user_id => self.id} | {:groups => {:user_id => self.id}})
  end
end
```

There's also the problem that you're searching the `friend`'s list of `groups` for a `Trip` object. Try changing that line to:

```
<% if !friend.all_trips.include?(@trip) %>
```

Or without the new method, something like this should work:

```
<% if !friend.groups.where(:trip_id => @trip.id).first %>
```

I don't see anything un-RESTful about your approach. RESTful in general means stateless. I.e. the only thing a response depends on is the HTTP method and the address. So as long as your not keeping state information in, say, the session, you should be following REST.

Comment: I tried using `<% if !friend.trips.include?(@trip) %>` but it didn't work. All users were still displayed. Your other solution `<% if !friend.groups.where(:trip_id => @trip.id).first %>` worked. What does .first do?

Comment: `.first` just pulls the first one from the database. It makes sure the that you've actually done the query and are dealing with the object. If you didn't do it, you would be dealing with an Arel object in all cases which would always be considered `true`.

Comment: Whoa! Why do you have `has_many :trips` defined **TWICE** in `User`? Get rid of that, and see what happens. Will update my answer.

Comment: Also, the routes wouldn't affect this. Routes only affect which combinations of HTTP methods and URLs your app responds to, and that's all sorted out long before you get to this code.

Comment: @hyngyn, I made some major edits based on what I think is a better understanding of your problem. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This is starting to make more sense now. This question was meant to be independent of the other question you answered. My problem was that I assumed that it was okay to have user has_many trips twice and that calling `users.trips` would return an array of all the trips the user created and belonged to. Thanks for clearing this up! :]